# php startup error

Tags: apache2, php, compiling

I'm receiving the following warning

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: dbase: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20190902
PHP    compiled with module API=20220829
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'dbase.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20220829/dbase.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/dbase.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20220829/dbase.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/dbase.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: The message means that the `dbase.so` library file is not compatible with your installed version of PHP. It will either need to be updated or removed for this warning message to go away 

Comment: You have PHP 8 installed and the database module is compiled for PHP 7.4.